# problem in parsing json in javascript and access value by key

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm receiving some error response in ajax error function;

```
    $.ajax(Request).error(function (Response) {
        var content = JSON.stringify(Response.responseText);
        var obj = JSON.parse(content);
        console.log("Response.responseText:",Response.responseText);
        console.log("Response.responseText.Message:", Response.responseText.Message);
        console.log("Response.responseText[Message]:", Response.responseText["Message"]);
        console.log("content:", content);
        console.log("content.Message:", content.Message);
        console.log("content[Message]:", content["Message"]);
        console.log("obj:", obj);
        console.log("obj.message:", obj.Message);
        console.log("obj[Message]:", obj["Message"]);
    });
```

**Here are outputs of console.log :**
[image]

I need **to access Message** but none of them create access to its value. How can I access Message?

**Main Question**

1. why all of them are undefined?
2. How can I access Message?

**Solution**

```
        var parsed= JSON.parse(startpaymentResponse.responseText);
        console.log("parsed:", parsed);
        console.log("parsed.Message:", parsed.Message);
        console.log("parsed[Message]:", parsed["Message"]);
```

Meanwhile when I copy Response.responseText to JSON Deserialize Online, everything is fine.

```
Response.responseText: {"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"model.Amount":["The field Amount must be a string or array type with a minimum length of '4'."],"model.TotalAmount":["The field TotalAmount must be a string or array type with a minimum length of '4'."]}}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the usage of `JSON.stringify(Response.responseText);`. To me it looks like the object is still actually a string even after `JSON.parse()` so maybe try parsing it to JSON once more or remove the above line i.e. `JSON.strignify()`.

Comment: @IrfanullahJan 
I was just testing all I could. I edited code and add json.parse(Response.responseText) but still not working.

Comment: Did you try removing, `JSON.stringify()` line and directly doing `JSON.parse(Response.responseText)`?

Comment: @IrfanullahJan, all of the output are there. check these lines:
   console.log("Response.responseText:",Response.responseText);
   console.log("Response.responseText.Message:", Response.responseText.Message);
and watch out the output picture as see their result.

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(Response.responseText).Message`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246903/discussion-between-irfanullah-jan-and-maryam-mohammadbagheri).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the problem is that `Response.responseText` is already a string. You don't need to do `JSON.stringify(Response.responseText)`. Please directly, parse it to JSON and then use the object:

```js
$.ajax(Request).error(function (Response) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(Response.responseText);
  console.log("obj.Message", obj.Message);
});
```